# Unable to run Visual Studio 2003 IDE on Windows 7

Tags: iis-7, windows-7, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

My machine has windows 7 and when I try to create a project from VS2003 IDE that is Dotnet v1.1 I'm getting the following error message:

> Visual Studio has detected that the specified web server is not running asp.net v1.1. you will be unable to run asp.net web application or services

I have searched Google and found some links for the same problem but I am still not able to create asp.net project v1.1 from VS2003 IDE.

Comment: Are you able to create a virtual directory in IIS, then make it an application, then set the ASP.NET version to 1.1? If so, then try doing that with the directory in which you want to create your application, before opening it in VS.

Comment: You should also consider this to be a subtle hint: maybe it's really _not_ ok to ignore ancient code. Maybe you really _do_ have to take the time to upgrade it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following article:

- [How to install ASP.NET 1.1 with IIS7 on Vista and Windows 2008](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx)

It says Windows Vista / Server 2008, however I am fairly certain that the same applied for Windows 7.

If you are having trouble understanding a specific part of the article then can you tell us which bit?

Comment: yes i follow the all the step in the above url but still getting the same error.the error is : Visual Studio has detected that the specified web server is not running asp.net v1.1. you will be unable to run asp.net web application or services

Comment: @Thomas: Were you able to resolve this issue? We have to test some ancient code written in vs2003 on a Windows 7 Professional box.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2003's lifecycle ended in 2007,

http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Visual+Studio&Filter=FilterNO

At that time, Windows 7 was not yet released, and such products should not be ever tested on Windows 7 internally.

So my guess is that you should continue using it on an older Windows platform (XP or Windows Server 2003).